# mysql database in gwt

Tags: mysql

how to upload and select image through mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u have to set **image path** in your database associated with your data,

when u want to update image, simply update the image path of corresponding data

and to select an image, use that image_path `in src`

```
<img src="here"
```